# How to decode Json data from php file into another php file?

Tags: php, json, api

**I am new in Creating API`s and I have created 2 files.php**
**1- API_ReadAll.php** ( Its an API code that after execution will return Json Result)

**Example Execute the below link:** 
http://localhost:8080/To%20work%20on/API_FUNCTIONS/API_ReadAll.php

**Output:**
Status Data Records:

```
[
   {
      STATUS_ID: "14",
      STATUS_CODE: "AP 2013",
      STATUS_DESCRIPTION: "Amazing wheel"
   }, {
      STATUS_ID: "13",
      STATUS_CODE: "AP55.0",
      STATUS_DESCRIPTION: "A23 Powder"
   }, {
      STATUS_ID: "16",
      STATUS_CODE: "AP525.0",
      STATUS_DESCRIPTION: "Power Drink"
   }
]
```

**2- Index.php** ( Its an php file consist of HTML elements and table to display the data retrieved from the the page above)

**I have tried to do the below:**

```
// path to your JSON file

$url = 'http://localhost:8080/To%20work%20on/API_FUNCTIONS/API_ReadAll.php'; 

$json = file_get_contents($url);

$data = json_decode($json,true);

 echo $data->STATUS_ID;

    foreach($data As $display){                     
      echo $display->STATUS_ID."<br>";
      echo $display->STATUS_CODE."<br>";
      echo $display->STATUS_DESCRIPTION."<br>";
    }
```

**Output:**

```
Warning: file_get_contents( http://localhost:8080/To%20work%20on/API_FUNCTIONS/API_ReadAll.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\To work on\Temp-Builder\SEED_STATUS.PHP on line 122

Notice: Trying to get property 'STATUS_ID' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\To work on\Temp-Builder\SEED_STATUS.PHP on line 125


Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\To work on\Temp-Builder\SEED_STATUS.PHP on line 125
```

**Question:**
How can I get and fetch the above Json inside the Index.php.

Answer (score 0):

I'd first of all recommend you to read through the following  guide [create simple rest api with php](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2017/02/create-simple-rest-api-in-php.html) (or any other tutorial of your choice), to get into the field of REST Apis with php.

Rather than handling api endpoints as file, you can use curl to perform a request against them. The result of that request can then be decoded to json with php's build in json_decode function.

To get you a starting point, I applied your approach to the curl sample found on [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/de/curl.examples.php):

```php
   // define api endpoint
   $url = 'http://localhost:8080/To%20work%20on/API_FUNCTIONS/API_ReadAll.php'; 

   // create curl resource
   $ch = curl_init();

   // set url
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

   //return the transfer as a string
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

   // $output contains the output string
   $output = curl_exec($ch);

   // close curl resource to free up system resources
   curl_close($ch);      

   $json_obj = json_decode($output)
```

I also noticed, that you're passing "true" as second parameter to `json_decode()`. That way you will receive an associative array rather than an object. But in your example you're treating it as an object.

Also be aware of the fact that *localhost* is only accessable within your local network. So the community here cannot acess your example if that was your intension.

Good luck

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------

Thank you for your time:

Regarding the link you provided to me to learn more about how to build the API. I did learn and build my API`s from that link and I successfully achieved what I am looking for.

Second about the code the comment of the link yes sure it will only have access from local serve, and I just posted like that trying to figure if this was a right way or not.

Regarding the code, I just tried your`s and still not working showing the following error:

Notice: Trying to get property 'STATUS_CODE' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\To work on\Temp-Builder\INDEX.PHP....

**Code:**

```php
    // define api endpoint
    $url = 'http://localhost:8080/To%20work%20on/Temp-Builder/API_FUNCTIONS/API_ReadAllSeed_Status.php'; 

    // create curl resource
     $ch = curl_init();

    // set url
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    //return the transfer as a string
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // $output contains the output string
        $output = curl_exec($ch);

    // close curl resource to free up system resources
        curl_close($ch);      

         $json_obj = json_decode($output);

        foreach ($json_obj as $display){

            echo $display->STATUS_ID."<br>";
            echo $display->STATUS_CODE."<br>";
            echo $display->STATUS_DESCRIPTION."<br>";
       }
```

Comment: First of all I thing editing an answer to form a reply is kind of an abuse of the edit function. Second, just read the error message. You are acessing sth. as an object which isn't. So I suggest this is caused by your json data which does not contain such an object at that position. But this is hard to say without further information but if you go through each step and inspect each variable it should be very easy to find out. Good luck and best regards